# How to get text from line number in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, office-2003, office-automation

Is it possible to get text (line or sentence) from a given line number in MS Word using office automation? I mean its ok if I can get either the text in the given line number or the sentence(s) itself which is a part of that line.

I am not providing any code because I have absolutely no clue how an MS Word is read using office automation. I can go about opening the file like this:

```
var wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
wordApp.Visible = false;
object file = path;
object misValue= Type.Missing; 
Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file, ref misValue, ref misValue,
                                           ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue,
                                           ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue,
                                           ref misValue, ref misValue, ref misValue);

//and rest of the code given I have a line number = 3 ?
```

Edit: To clarify @Richard Marskell - Drackir's doubt, though text in MS Word is a long chain of string, office automation does still let us know line number. In fact I get the line number itself from another piece of code, like this:

```
Word.Revision rev = //SomeRevision
object lineNo = rev.Range.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterLineNumber);
```

For instance say the Word file looks like this:

```
fix grammatical or spelling errors

clarify meaning without changing it correct minor mistakes add related resources or links
always respect the original author
```

Here there are 4 lines.

Comment: What is considered a new line? For example, is it when there is some kind of break (line, paragraph, section, etc.) or visually when you open word and see the "page" or something else?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir I haven't talked anything about a new line. In MS Word every line has a line number. Even a blank line has a line number. If I have the `int` line number, is it possible to get the line itself?

Comment: Perhaps he needs to look at Range check out MSDN site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx%28VS.80%29.aspx also what given text are you looking for you can also do a word search as well using Microsoft.Interop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kw65a0we%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am not wanting a word search. I want whatever is present in line number say 3. I do not know what to search for. Nevertheless your link provides some insights..

Comment: It seems to me that line numbers (and their contents) depends greatly on the margins of the document, the view mode, font-size, etc. Take for example, if you have a paragraph of text and you switch the view mode to Web, or you make the font size smaller, or you change the margin widths, all of these will change what you see on each line. Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems to me that the only way to figure out what's on each line is to know what a line actually constitutes.

Comment: if you are wanting whats in line number 3 why not read the contents of the File into a List<string> and get the List<string> index position [2] of that List<T> variable.. what about the formatting from the word document.. I think that this question needs to be refactored..

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir It doesnt matter in the application what font size the word text is in, or if another font size would change that. Just want to get the line for the present formatting corresponding to the line number.

Comment: @DJKRAZE exactly, but how do I read the contents to a list?

Comment: @DJKRAZE That's why I'm asking my question. I'm pretty sure that, in a Word doc, a paragraph is stored as a long string of text with a paragraph break at the end, not as individual lines.

Comment: @nawfal Are the lines individual (breaks between each) or is it paragraphs of text (where one string of text may span multiple lines)?

Comment: I think that a slower approach would be your best bet.. read eachline into a List<T> or Dictionary<int,string[]> which is over kill and then while you are reading to end of that stream .. you can tell what's on the lines.. hopefully you will debug and step thru this so that you can actually see what contents are being returned I would be curious to know if you are getting what you expect or think that you should be getting.. this is totally different for a .TXT file I hope that you are aware...

Comment: I will post an example down below of 1 line of code that will read the contents into a List<T> it's up to you do write the code to check or loop thru the List<T> after I do that.. fair enough

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks, I can manage the rest.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir Wait for the update in the question. Let me

Comment: not a problem also the reason we ask the questions is because many of us are here to help and sometimes it's' hard / difficult to understand what the OP really wants without asking without trying to cause the OP any frustration..remember nawfal.. there are a lot of bright minds here whom are more than willing to help those in a bind .. we all had to start coding once upon a time too ...

Comment: @nawfal - If the third line were to span onto the next line, would it be considered five lines or still four where one spans?

Comment: It has to be 5 lines. You can test it with a Word application. You can see the line number for each line in the document. In simple terms, that line which Word naturally detects as a line!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately after some epic searching I got a solution.

```
    object file = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Answer.doc";

    Word.Application wordObject = new Word.ApplicationClass();
    wordObject.Visible = false;

    object nullobject = Missing.Value;
    Word.Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open
        (ref file, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
        ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
        ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
        ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);

    String strLine;
    bool bolEOF = false;

    docs.Characters[1].Select();

    int index = 0;
    do
    {
        object unit = Word.WdUnits.wdLine;
        object count = 1;
        wordObject.Selection.MoveEnd(ref unit, ref count);

        strLine = wordObject.Selection.Text;
        richTextBox1.Text += ++index + " - " + strLine + "\r\n"; //for our understanding

        object direction = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
        wordObject.Selection.Collapse(ref direction);

        if (wordObject.Selection.Bookmarks.Exists(@"\EndOfDoc"))
            bolEOF = true;
    } while (!bolEOF);

    docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
    wordObject.Quit(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
    docs = null;
    wordObject = null;
```

[Here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/514832-how-to-read-a-line-from-ms-word.html)'s the genius behind the code. Follow the link for some more explanation on how it works.

Comment: your wordObject = null, will not dispose of the wordObject you need to do this instead System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( wordObject );

Comment: Are you so sure? I do not get any `"WINWORD"` instance in taskbar even though I did not use Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Comment: well think about how you release COM objects in the past.. even though this is Interop its best to use it's Marshalling ReleaseComObject call to release objects this is not the same as in the C# .net Objects.. do some research on it to get a better understanding.. plus I know this from tons of experience when utilizing Microsoft.Office.Interop

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir thanks. size of your name helped me to post this short a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to read standard text .txt files
Here is something that you can use to read the files with one call

```
List<string> strmsWord = 
    new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(yourFilePath+ YourwordDocName));
```

if you want to loop thru and see what the items that were returned use something like this

```
 foreach (string strLines in strmsWord )
 {
   Console.WriteLine(strLines);
 }
```

or

I totally forgot about something Word docs are probably in binary format so look at this and read the contents into a RichTextBox and from there you could either get at the line number you want or load it into a list after words.. this link will show you 
[Reading from a Word Doc](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10046526/how-to-read-word-doc-using-filestream-and-streamreader-class.aspx)
if you want to read the XML Formatting of the word Document:
here is a  good link as to checkout as well 
[ReadXML Format of a Word Document](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2011/09/reading-ms-word-2007-document-in-docx.html)

This onne is an even easier example reads contents into the ClipBoard 
[Load Word into ClipBoard](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Globalking/fileAccessingusingcsharp02242006050207AM/fileAccessingusingcsharp.aspx)

Comment: This would only work for text documents. New Word documents are stored in a compressed XML format.

Comment: May be this should help considering my target is just Word 2003

Comment: @nawfal Actually, I think it's even worse there. I don't know the format, it may be a custom binary format. Try opening it in notepad and you'll see that it's nowhere near a simple text file. :(

Comment: I don't think your new edit will work due to the reasons I gave in my question above. Specifically that formatting, margins, view, etc. all affect how the lines are numbered. This means that copying them into a text box is going to change how they're laid out as well. Especially since that code appears to only be getting the text from the clipboard and nothing of the formatting (`data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();`). It's closer though.

Comment: In fact the first example too doesnt work :( The list gets a series of strings which doesn't match the actual line count. But I think I can get an answer using the range and revision properties.

Comment: @DJKRAZE The Word doc copying code was actually the closest, I think, so far. :P

Comment: I still have it if you need me to repost it

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir How is it closer? It only gets a chain of long string and nothing related to line number

Comment: You can't get the line number each line in itself is a line number.. nawfal I believe that you have a misunderstanding of how to read lines / string in text it's not going to explictly say line#1 ....etc do you follow if the first line says 1. for example then you would have to do a word search perhaps to determine what line you are on.. even better search for "1." I hope that is what you are talking about

Comment: Why would not I get a line from line number? I posted in the question how I get the line number of each revision. So I thought why would I not get line back if I have the line number initially. May be I did not get you. Anyway I got another solution which I posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = new Word.Application();
object miss = Missing.Value;
object path = @"D:\viewstate.docx";
object readOnly = true;
var docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, 
                               ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, 
                               ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, 
                               ref miss, ref miss);
string totaltext = "";

object unit = Word.WdUnits.wdLine;
object count = 1;
word.Selection.MoveEnd(ref unit, ref count);
totaltext = word.Selection.Text;

TextBox1.Text = totaltext;
docs.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
word.Quit(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
docs = null;
word = null;
```

Comment: does this give line number or anything similar?

Comment: It returns the line text depending on the line number

Comment: where am I passing the line number?

Comment: count is the line number :)

Comment: oh ok, havent tested myself, but come on this is exactly what I posted as answer.

Comment: dont forget to add assembly microsoft.office.interop.word and System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;