# How to extract text from a Word document?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to extract specific text from a Word document based on coordinates. I have searched many sites on this requirement, but with no luck. How to set the coordinates to the Word document text?

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates"?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181085/how-to-get-text-from-line-number-in-ms-word) question has a solution for finding the text of a certain line number in a Word doc.

Obviously you'll need a bit of extra code to search the strLine variable for a specific substring or whatever, but the hard work is done there I think.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of the Word file, there are two object models. The older style .doc files used one that had paragraphs, tables, and the like. The .docx files have an XML based structure that's a totally different model.

If you need to support both formats, you've got your work cut out for you.

Here's a link to the documentation:

[Word Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx)